# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in impersonating the client

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, sqlclient

i have published my asp.net MVC 3 web application locally using IIS 7 express and visual developer express 2010, but when i tired to login to the application it returned the following error:-

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in impersonating the client. The connection will be closed.
```

so what might be causing this problme?
BR
**Edit:-
the current connection string is :-**

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="ElearningEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Elearning.csdl|res://*/Models.Elearning.ssdl|res://*/Models.Elearning.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MScProject.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled SSPI in your connection string, you might no longer be able to perform it when the SQL server is on a separate tier than your web server. You could use standard SQL Server authentication with a username and password in this case.

Comment: how i can do that ,,,this is actually my first deployment for an MVC web application using IIS 7.. thanks in advance

Comment: You change your connection string to use `User Id` and `Password` tokens. Then you configure your SQL database server to accept this user. The way to configure this is out of topic on StackOverflow. You should ask this question on http://serverfault.com if you have problems configuring your server or some more specific questions.

Comment: i have edited my original post to include the current connection string.

Comment: @johnG, in your connection string you have set `Integrated Security=True`. Also you seem to be using SQL Express. Are you sure that such SQL instance is installed on your target server? How do you intend to host your database on the target server? What SQL Server version do you intend to use? Remember that SQL Express is fine for development purposes but once you ship your application you might consider using a more advanced version of SQL Server. Checkout the following for different connection strings you might use: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Comment: But as I said, if you are unfamiliar with different SQL Server editions and configurations, you'd better ask your question on http://serverfault.com. Such discussions are off-topic here. StackOverflow is a programming related Q&A site where you could ask questions about the development of your application, not about how to configure SQL Server and which edition is right for you.